# NSString or UILabel with a backslash through a letter

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to make certain letters in a word have a slash through it? I have a tableview with a list of words, and I want to draw a slash through "silent letters"

What would be the best way to approach creating UILabel's to look like this?

[image]

Comment: Other than drawing a UIView or graphic on top, you could find a font that has it.

Comment: @Tim A Font wouldn't help, if it needs different color.

Comment: You MIGHT be able to do it with NSAttributedString -- I haven't played with that much.  Otherwise you need to overlay another view over the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the best would be to not use `UILabel` at all.

Create your own `UIView` subclass, override `drawRect` and draw the text. Then draw the lines over letters. If you have the font and the text, calculating the position for the line is pretty trivial.